# Is there an Android app similar to RunAsDate for Windows?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm looking for an **Android app** that can open apps I want using the date I specify instead of the system date.

Something similar to the [RunAsDate](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html) program that is available for Windows:

> RunAsDate is a small utility that allows you to run a program in the
>   date and time that you specify. This utility doesn't change the
>   current system date and time of your computer, but it only injects the
>   date/time that you specify into the desired application. You can run
>   multiple applications simultaneously, each application works with
>   different date and time, while the real date/time of your system
>   continues to run normally.

Like for example if I always want to open WhatsApp using a certain date.